# Detecting the end of an animation using a handler

Tags: android, android-handler

In the code below I have 3 images stored in an `imageArray`. I'm animating images using a handler, but it's looping continuously, and I want it to only to run the animation once.

What I want to do is to see if it gets to the 3rd image, then stop the animation.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_grade_four__place_value);
     final ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1);
     final int[] imageArray = {(R.drawable.pl1),
                               (R.drawable.pl2),
                               (R.drawable.pl3)};

    final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                int i = 0;

                public void run() {
                    image1.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);

                    i++;
                    if (i > imageArray.length - 1) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 300); // for interval...
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500); // for initial delay..
            btn2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a [Drawable Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) as opposed to a `Handler`?

You'd basically create an animation set in xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pl1" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pl2" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pl3" android:duration="300" />
</animation-list>
```

Let's call this file `animation_drawable.xml` and put it in the `drawable` folder. Afterwards, just use the following code to start the animation:

```
final AnimationDrawable drawable = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animation_drawable);
image1.setImageDrawable(drawable);
drawable.start();

image1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        image1.clearAnimation();
        // Handle your animation ending here
    }
}, drawable.getDuration());
```

That's it! I know it's a hack solution, but I thing Drawable animation makes the code clearer and more compact, but listening to the end of the animation requires a bit of workaround.

Comment: yes sir i previously use animation drawable, but also i don't know how to end it to work other stuff after animation xD.

Comment: To stop the animation, you just need to do `image1.clearAnimation()`. Just updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: i have a question sir. what is the difference of getResources and getBackgroundResource??. thank you for the answer

Comment: I don't think there's a method called `getBackgroundResource()`. There's a `setBackgroundResource()` though which is a method of `View` and lets you set directly the background resource without the need to do `getResources().getDrawable()`.

Comment: im sorry its getBackgroundResource my bad. thanks i'll try this

Comment: last sir. can i insert the run method inside a touchListener??

Comment: Sure, no problem about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
i++;
if (i > imageArray.length - 1) {
    i = 0;
}
handler.postDelayed(this, 300);
```

to

```
if (i < imageArray.length - 1) {
    handler.postDelayed(this, 300);
}
i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Runnable code posts itself into handler with delay after each pass. Just instead setting `i=0;` when your `i` variable is bigger or equal array size - return from `run()` method. It will not reach `handler.postDelayed(this, 300)`, so next frame will be not displayed.

Sample:

```
    final int[] imageArray = {R.drawable.ic, R.drawable.ic, R.drawable.ic};
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        private int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            i++;
            if(i > imageArray.length - 1) {
                Log.e("ASD", "Done");
                return;
            }
            Log.e("ASD", "Preparing next iteration");
            handler.postDelayed(this, 300);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
```

Anyway, it's not best way to provide frame animation.

Comment: can you give me a sample sir?

Comment: Here you go, but as above, it's not best way for frame animation.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule the Runnable only if the end of the image array is not reached:

```
public void run() {
    image1.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);

    i++;
    if (i < imageArray.length) {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 300); // for interval...
    }
}
```